# TPL parallel Selenium webdriver instance with Parallel.For - NOT TEST

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, multiple-instances

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     driver = new ChromeDriver(App.Library.FullName, options, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
}
```

The above code easily creates 10 instances of chrome driver.

But if I try to do like this :

```
Parallel.For(0,(items.Count() - 1), i => {

     if (theURL.IsWellFormedOriginalString())
     {
        if (menuBrowser.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(App.Library.FullName, options, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
        }
        driver.Url = theURL.ToString();
     }
});
```

Then when it comes to the driver initialization line, it do not execute for more than once and normally execute the next line and gets out of the loop. Yes, only one instance initiated.

Can anyone tell, why this is happening and how to make it work?